# TypeScript defaultIfUndefined function typing

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a simple function, which returns a `defaultValue`, if `value === undefined`.

The function is super simple:

```js
const defaultIfUndefined = (value, defaultValue) => {
    return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

But the typings / type inference won't work.

**The function should simply remove `undefined` from the types.**

I tried several different things, but there's always some error.

1.

```js
const defaultIfUndefined = <T>(value: T, defaultValue: Exclude<T, undefined>): Exclude<T, undefined> => {
    return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

2.

```js
const defaultIfUndefined = <T, U extends Exclude<T, undefined>>(value: T, defaultValue: U): U => {
    return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

3.

```js
const defaultIfUndefined = <T, U extends T | undefined>(value: U, defaultValue: Exclude<U, undefined>): Exclude<U, undefined> => {
    return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

4.

```js
const defaultIfUndefined = <T, U extends T | undefined, V extends Exclude<U, undefined>>(value: U, defaultValue: V): V => {
    return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

**The first example is working fine, as long as I `return ... as any`.**

But is there some way to get this working without `as any`?

--

[Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20defaultIfUndefined%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T%2C%20defaultValue%3A%20Exclude%3CT%2C%20undefined%3E)%3A%20Exclude%3CT%2C%20undefined%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20defaultValue%20%3A%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20defaultIfUndefined%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20Exclude%3CT%2C%20undefined%3E%3E(value%3A%20T%2C%20defaultValue%3A%20U)%3A%20U%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20defaultValue%20%3A%20value%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20defaultIfUndefined%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20T%20%7C%20undefined%3E(value%3A%20U%2C%20defaultValue%3A%20Exclude%3CU%2C%20undefined%3E)%3A%20Exclude%3CU%2C%20undefined%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20defaultValue%20%3A%20value%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20defaultIfUndefined%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20T%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20V%20extends%20Exclude%3CU%2C%20undefined%3E%3E(value%3A%20U%2C%20defaultValue%3A%20V)%3A%20V%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20defaultValue%20%3A%20value%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20val%20%3D%20null%20as%20(null%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20boolean)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20defaultIfUndefined(val%2C%20true)%3B) to TypeScript Playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional types that contain unresolved type parameter will genrally require a type assertion. This is due to the fact that typescript does not do much math on such types, it just checks for exact matches of the conditional type.

A solution would be to avoid conditional types:

```
const defaultIfUndefined = <T>(value: T | undefined | null, defaultValue: T & {}): T => {
  return value || defaultValue;
}

let a : string | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "" : null;
let aNotNull = defaultIfUndefined(a, "") // string
```

Just a note on the `T & {}`. If you change it to just `T`, typescript will be too aggressive  in inferring a literal type, the `& {}` fixed that.

Comment: Thank you. The `& {}` did the trick! `fn = <T>(value: T | undefined, defaultValue: T & {}): T => { return value === undefined ? defaultValue : value; }` works as expected.